# How to automatically run tests when there's any change in my project (Django)?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, nose

At the moment I am running `python manage.py test` every once in a while after I make significant changes in my django project. Is it possible to run those tests automatically whenever I change and save a file in my project? It'll be useful to detect bugs earlier (I know rails has something like this with rspec). I am using nose and django-nose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nosy) will help if you want to run your test suite on code changes rather than commits.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it looks like what I need for the moment being. Would you by chance know if nosy can easily be added to django-nose (like as a plug-in: [django-nose short explanation on that](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose#custom-plugins))?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there something like 'autotest' for Python unittests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108892/is-there-something-like-autotest-for-python-unittests)

Answer (score 50):

Use [entr](http://entrproject.org/):

1. $ `brew install entr`
2. $ `find . -name '*.py' | entr python ./manage.py test`

---

Or, for extra credit, combine it with [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/):

```
$ ack --python | entr python ./manage.py test
```

---

If you want it to even find new files as you add them:

```
$ until ack -f --python | entr -d python ./manage.py test; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: And if you are using silver searcher, change "ack -f --python" to "ag -l --python"

Comment: Hadn't heard of [The Silver Searcher](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/), thanks for the tip!

Comment: never heard of `entr`. it`s even more useful than what I was looking for. thanks :)

Comment: @c17r One year later, and I'm still using `ag` (silver searcher) almost every single workday.

Comment: Also consider [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) as an alt to ag/ack.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt I checked out rg about a year ago, but at that time it had strange output (lots of empty lines) compared to the equivalent ag call, and I saw no reason to figure out why, as ag was working well for me.

Comment: I would later check out `rg` again (possibly right after writing that comment) and I am now using it every day. Good stuff.

Answer (score 18):

***py.test answer (which also works for nose):***

```
pip install pytest-xdist
py.test -f # will watch all subfolders for changes, and rerun the tests
```

Since py.test understands nose, this works for nose too.

Comment: Nose is no longer maintained, and py.test is just oh so much better and more pythonic anyways.

Answer (score 12):

Another Javascript dev here, I've found `nodemon` (https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to work pretty well. By default it watches `*.js` files but that's configurable with the `--ext` flag. To use it, do:

```
npm install -g nodemon
cd /your/project/dir/
nodemon --ext py --exec "python manage.py test"
```

Now, whenever a `*.py` file changes, it'll re-run your command. It even finds new files.

Comment: I also have been doing this, but I find when tests finish it registers as a "crash" and sometimes the teardown doesn't seem to run. Haven't quite figured it out, but wondering if you'd hit similar problems?

Comment: @dcsan I haven't but I haven't touched the project I was using this in for a long time either. Sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a JavaScript developer so I used the tools JS developer have built with Node.js to achieve the same goal in my projects. It is very simple but you also need to install nodeJS to get it working.

I created a file called gruntfile.js in my project root directory:

```
//gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      files: ['*.py'],
      tasks: ['shell']
    },
    shell: {
      test: {
        command: 'python main_test.py'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

What it's doing is basically watching any file in that directory that has a py extension and if they changed it execute a shell command which in this case is my python test (you might wanna change it, my test name was main_test.py). In order to run this grunt script you need to install Node.js and after that you will have npm in your global path. after that you need to insall a few node modules as well. All these modules except grunt-cli will be stored in your current folder so make sure you are at the root of your project or what ever folder you put that gruntfile.js in. then run the fallowing commands.

```
npm install grunt-cli -g
npm install grunt
npm install grunt-contrib-watch
npm install grunt-shell
```

Don't worry about the size, these are very small modules. Now that you have every thing setup you can simply run `grunt` and it will start watching your py files and when you saved them it will run your tests. It may not be best way for running python tests but as I said I'm a JavaScript developer and I think Grunt has provided a very simple way of executing tests even for other languages so I use it.

Answer (score 9):

I just tried [`nose-watch`](https://github.com/lukaszb/nose-watch) and it worked fantastic! install the plugin and run the test with the `--with-watch` option.

**Update**: :( it does not seem to work well when running tests from django-nose's manage.py helper.

Eventually I opted to use [tdaemon](https://github.com/brunobord/tdaemon), which supports django, although might require a bit of fiddling as well for full fledged projects.

For example here is how I ran it for my django project:

```
tdaemon -t django --custom-args=a_specific_app_to_test -d --ignore-dirs logs
```

The `--custom-args` was to focus tests to specific app (same as you would do `python manage.py test a_specific_app_to_test`

The `-d` argument is to enable debug logging, which prints which file change triggered the run.

The `--ignore-dirs` was necessary because my tests wrote to the logs (which in itself is a problem!) and `tdaemon` went into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

I'm used watchr, something like [Watchr](http://criticallog.thornet.net/2011/03/08/autotesting-with-watchr-growl-and-phpunit/)

Answer (score 2):

I did this using gulp. Install gulp-shell:

```
npm install gulp-shell --save-dev
```

And in the gulpfile.js:

```
var shell = require('gulp-shell')

gulp.task('run-tests', shell.task([
   'python3 manage.py test']))

gulp.task('watch', function(){
   gulp.watch(['./your-project-name/**/*.html', './your-project-name/**/*.py'], ['run-tests']);
});

gulp.task('default',['run-tests','watch']);
```

And it runs the tests anytime there are changes saved to any .py or .html files!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django Supervisor](https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor) on top of Django. This will avoid the use of a CI tool (which may be useful in any case, this isn't invalidating the other response - maybe just complementary).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting up [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) and [sniffer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sniffer). It's quite easy to setup and works great. Something along the lines of [this scent.py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19586098/8207) was the only customization I needed. Then you can just run `sniffer -x myapp.tests`.

Nose comes with some other goodies that make tests a bit nicer to work with as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you use git control code, another way to is use git hook [pre-commit](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample)

maybe error like `remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'`, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4100577/7007942

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest way is to use gulp as recommended by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29514474/733601). Note that `gulp-shell` (recommended by other answers) is actually [blacklisted by gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json), but thankfully you don't even need a plugin. Try this instead:

```js
// gulpfile.js

const { watch } = require('gulp')
var exec = require('child_process').exec

function test (cb) {
  exec('python manage.py test', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout)
    console.log(stderr)
    cb(err)
  })
}

exports.default = function () {
  watch('./**/*.py', test)
}
```

In the past, I've tried many of the options suggested in other answers. This one was comparatively painless. It's helpful if you have some knowledge of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Gulp task to automatically run `./manage.py test` whenever any specified Python files are changed or removed. You'll need Node for this.

First, install Gulp:

```
yarn add -D gulp@next
```

Then use the following `gulpfile.js` and make any necessary adjustments:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const gulp = require('gulp');

const runDjangoTests = (done) => {
  const task = exec('./manage.py test --keepdb', {
    shell: '/bin/bash', // Accept SIGTERM signal. Doesn't work with /bin/sh
  });

  task.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  task.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

  task.on('exit', () => {
    done();
  });

  return task;
};

gulp.task('test', runDjangoTests);

gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
  let activeTask;
  const watcher = gulp.watch('**/*.py', {
    // Ignore whatever directories you need to
    ignored: ['.venv/*', 'node_modules'],
  });

  const runTask = (message) => {
    if (activeTask) {
      activeTask.kill();
      console.log('\n');
    }

    console.log(message);
    activeTask = runDjangoTests(done);
  };

  watcher.on('change', (path) => {
    runTask(`File ${path} was changed. Running tests:`);
  });

  watcher.on('unlink', (path) => {
    runTask(`File ${path} was removed. Running tests:`);
  });
});
```

Then simply run `node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js watch` to run the task :)

Answer (score 0):

https://pycrunch.com/

One of key features - run only impacted tests on file changes. Available as plugin for PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu this script works, after installing `inotifywait` (`sudo apt install inotify-tools`):

```
inotifywait -qrm -e close_write * |
while read -r filename event; do
  python manage.py test accord
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `entr` you can use [`watchexec`](https://github.com/watchexec/watchexec) with

```bash
brew install watchexec

watchexec -rc -e py -- python ./manage.py test
```

with options

```bash
-r             # restart
-c             # clear screen
-e extensions  # list of file extensions to filter by
```

Answer (score -6):

You'll need a continuous integration server, something like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll definitely check into that when I use Selenium. For now, I just do basic tests using the 'fake' server shipped with Django.

Comment: Jenkins has nothing to do with Selenium. You can easily use it with normal unit tests.

Comment: Worth mentioning here the [`django-jenkins`](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins) project.

Comment: I think this a bit overblown for just a file save.  Is there something like the rails `guard` gem? but for python?

Comment: that answer is too heavy for TDD. The OP asked about how to write the fast-n-easy tests that are the heartbeat of what Jenkins run. your advice would have long turnaround and possibly require a check-in