# django - Run tests upon starting server

Tags: python, django

How can I configure my Django server to run tests from `tests.py` when starting the server with `python manage.py runserver`? Right now, I have to run tests through `python manage.py test articles`. (Note: I am using Django 1.8)

Comment: Create a bash alias or run them in sequence?

Comment: `bash` alias is a way to go.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does work. I'll close this if I don't get another answer soon. Thank you!

Comment: why do you want to run tests when you start your server?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro: Constant quality checking. It's also especially useful if  I make changes to my models or HTML templates.

Comment: Possibly related to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166532/how-to-automatically-run-tests-when-theres-any-change-in-my-project-django)

Comment: @danielcorin: Almost related, but not quite. That post wants to run the test suite every time a change is applied, while I only want to run it every time I start the server.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @limelights:

> Create a bash alias or run them in sequence?

I've adapted that answer to this line of code (for bash):

`alias runserver="sudo python ~/testsite/manage.py test articles; sudo python ~/testsite/manage.py runserver 192.168.1.245:90` (as one line)

Using `runserver` runs the test suite and opens the server. An added perk is that I can run it from any location without having to go into the `~/testsite` directory.