# What is the equivalent of autotest/guard for django

Tags: django, automated-tests

When I code in Ruby on Rails, I rely on Guard to listen for changes to the code base so when I'm writing tests, I don't need to manually run the tests in the file I'm working on each time.

https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec

What is the closest thing to thing for django so I can enjoy the same workflow?

Specifically, what I want to do is be able to have tests run, based on:

- what run tests based on files I have changed, and not
- know whether to run the test command based on whether a test run is currently taking place
- work with existing tests written with unittest
- work with something like factory boy to let me use factories instead of fixtures

I've used nose before, and pytest and I'm comfortable using both - but I haven't used many of pytests extensive set of libraries.

What are my options for this?

Comment: Refer this question for the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166532/how-to-automatically-run-tests-when-theres-any-change-in-my-project-django